# User management in snap

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I've just begun my first Snap application, and there is something I do not quite understand. How exactly am I supposed to manage my users?

There already appears to be an [`AuthUser`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap/docs/Snap-Snaplet-Auth.html#t:AuthUser) type for dealing with user authentication. My question is more about additional user data. Such as collecting their name, location, etc.

I have found the [snap-auth](https://github.com/snapframework/snap-auth#usage-example-1) module on GitHub outlining the creation of a `User` type that has the `AuthUser` embedded inside. My only concern is that it is quite old and may not be the current best practise in this area.

Comment: Auth snaplet backends all need to be able to serialize the `AuthUser` structure - so including your user data within `AuthUser` would be somewhat limiting. Instead, it's common to treat your user data like all other data in your app (separately handled), and relate it back to the `AuthUser` by the `AuthUser.userLogin`  (edit: spelling)

Comment: @ImAlsoGreg Why do you suggest using `AuthUser.userLogin` instead of `AuthUser.userId`?

Comment: Oh, thanks. As @mightybyte mentioned elsewhere, `AuthUser.userId` is a better choice, for those times when you might let users change their login name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I usually deal with additional user data is to put it in a separate table keyed by the key from the AuthUser type.